# How to get Window reference (CGWindow, NSWindow or WindowRef) from CGWindowID in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, nswindow, window-managers

How to get Window reference (CGWindow, NSWindow or WindowRef) from CGWindowID in Swift on XCode 7.3 Mac Playground?

I referenced from Apple's document - [Window Manager Reference](http://n.ethz.ch/~upeter/download/carbon_port/Dokus/API_REF/Window_Manager.pdf), and from the sample code [SonofGrab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html), but I didn't find an answer in obj-C nor Swift.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for NSWindow from CGWindowID

```
NSWindow * ns_window;
ns_window = [NSApp windowWithWindowNumber: windowNumber];
```

To get CGWindowID from NSWindow use

```
CGWindowID window_id = (CGWindowID)[ns_window windowNumber];
```

Comment: Are you sure that's how you get the `CGWindowId`? The docs for `windowNumber` say this: "note that this isn’t the same as the global window number assigned by the window server"

Comment: Also, note that `[NSApp windowWithWindowNumber:]` only works for windows owned by your application.

Comment: After some testing, `windowNumber` does appear to be correct!